# HTML5 routing in Angular2 App with ASP.Net Core MVC and ASP.Net Web Api

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am develop Angular2 App with ASP.Net Core MVC and ASP.Net Web Api.

Here is my basic architecture.

**ASP.Net Core MVC Project (MyProject.Web)**

- **Nuget**, **npm**, and **bower** is used for dependencies. **Bower** is used to copy the npm dependencies from `node_modules` to `wwwroot/libs/`
- `Home/Index` controller's action delivers the first page which loads **Angular2** and other dependencies.
- Templates are loaded from ActionMethods i.e. `Home/About`
- **SystemJS** loads the modules.
- Angular2's http service calls the ASP.Net Web Api Project (a separate project than mvc)

**ASP.Net Web Api Project (MyProject.Api)**
 - Each Controllers is designated for CRUD operations of an entity, and responses to Angular2's http

**Problem**: I am not able to use HTML5 routing and am forced to hash routing because html5 routing calls the server and my MVC project does not have the corresponding controller. So server doesn't return anything.

Comment: You should be able to configure your server to support HTML5 pushState. It just needs to return `index.html` for unknown URLs

Comment: First, there is no index.html, as mentioned above the action methods are used for delivering html. Second, What if my AngularApp is requesting a resource (i.e. image, css, js file etc) which exists but is available no more and I want to display an error. But in your solution, the index action is returned? How to deal with it?

Comment: You can return a 404 response (not rewrite to index.html) for requests that try to access resources in the `asset` directory (or distinguish by other criteria)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem: I am not able to use HTML5 routing and am forced to hash routing because html5 routing calls the server and my MVC project does not have the corresponding controller. So server doesn't return anything.

Adding # into route path is probably the most common solution in a case like you, but...

Do you have any particular reason for using MVC with Angular?

In my opinion, you don't need MVC - you could just create **empty** ASP.NET Core project and add into your HTML/Angular app - clean, simple, comfortable and no conflicts between MVC and Angular ;)

Add your files (including `index.html`) into `wwwroot` and update your `Startup.cs` file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
            app.UseDefaultFiles(); <- Add this line before UseStaticFiles
            app.UseStaticFiles();            
    }
}
```

**Please find more information:**

- [ASP.NET Core Working with Static Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files)
- [Make index.html as startup file in ASP.NET Core](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/make-index-html-startup-file-in-aspnet-core/)

Comment: This is what I have seen most tutorials say. However, I want to take benefit from Razor as well, (thought I haven't so far, but I am think eventually I will) i.e. I will display the static info (info that barely changes frequently) via ViewModel and will not let angular use http calls for that info. What do you say about that use case?

Comment: The answer depends on your design and implementation - if you are going to SPA than Angular will be your main technology and you will not see benefits from MVC.

Comment: Of course, you could create MVC app (as the main technology) with Angular as an additional (supporting) technology, but I assume you are not interested that direction.

Comment: About your example `and will not let angular use http calls for that info` - what the problem? Angular or MVC - the same http request.

Comment: Currently, I'm working on a project designed to use benefits from both MVC and AngularJS,,, and I didn't notice any use of MVC except overcomplicated design. (Sorry for my English, I hope you understand what I mean).

Comment: Your English is good, don't worry about that. Thanks you didn't notice my typos in last comment ;-). Well, yes it's a single page app, and so far apparently there is no benefit of MVC, but I am going to write a use case in my next comment.

Comment: Imagine you loaded a partialview from mvc, and loaded as template in Angular2. That view displays two divs, one contains logged in user's details and the second displays the some other info, and both these info divs are required on some pages. Now would it be better to do separate http class for (1) the template (2) data for the first div (3) data for the second div. What do you say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133172/discussion-between-super-coder-and-lukasz-makowej).

Comment: Sorry for late answer. For me splitting code between two frameworks (MVC & Angular) is like adding additional work, but if you see the reason/benefits then do it - it's nothing wrong with this... It's only about what do you want ;)

Comment: But in that case, we are backing to problem with routes - so add '#' or change default route configuration in Startup.cs

Comment: Thank you. I have moved the templates from MVC Views to HTML files and consuming directly. Thanks again for your help .

Comment: I think now I will be able to use HTML5 routing.

Answer (score 6):

If you plan to use on IIS, you can use URL rewriting module. It basically tells web server to rewrite all routing URLs to index.html. .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule"
resourceType="Unspecified"/>
   </handlers>
   <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
      <rewrite>
         <rules>
            <rule name="Angular 2 pushState routing" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url=".*" />
               <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern=".*\.[\d\w]+$" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
            </rule>
         </rules>
      </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

"I am not able to use HTML5 routing and am forced to hash routing because html5 routing calls the server and my MVC project does not have the corresponding controller. So server doesn't return anything"

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices

Look for the Routing helper aka spa services nuget and the spa fallback route.

When no serverside route is found and the route has no file extension then the index.html should be returned to the client where the current route is interpreted as a client side route by angular router.